# Discord.js: member.guild.channels.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

So I'm trying to make a welcome message for my discord bot right now, but somehow I have a really weird problem where apparently members.guild.channels.find() is not a function.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{

    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");

    if(!channel) return;

    const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(pink)
        .setAuthor('IdealBot', 'https://hypixel.net/attachments/ideal-png.1417277/', 'https://hypixel.net/threads/ideal-ideal-%E2%9D%96-level-52-%E2%9D%96-sweaty-skyblock-guild-%E2%9D%96-top-10-sb-guild-%E2%9D%96-splashes-%E2%9D%96-events-%E2%9D%96-recruiting.2500755/')
        .setTitle('Welcome!')
        .setDescription(`${member} just joined the discord! Make sure to read #rules!`)
        .setThumbnail(message.user.avatarURL)
        .setFooter('Note: The maximum amount of answers is 9.')
        .setTimestamp();

    channel.send(welcomeEmbed);
});
```

Yet when I try to run it, I get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

I'm pretty sure I've used this before, does anybody know where this error could originate from?

Answer (score 5):

You typed `member.guild.channel.find`. Change it to `member.guild.channels.cache.find`, since it was changed a while ago. See [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, I guess the property you try to access does not exist. Looks like `channels` must be used instead of `channel`, see below:

`const channel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");`

Also see [Welcome Message every X users](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/examples/welcome-message-every-x-users.md) example, there the property is as well accessed by `.channels`

Comment: I'm using channels, was just a typo on the post

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also, to solve it try member.guild.channels.find()

Also, the message.user.avatarURL will not work unless you have brackets -
i.e message.user.avatarURL() as it is a function.

Let me know if this works

Comment: No probs - maybe try finding the channel by guild id?

Comment: @Ramiz Wachtler already solved it by adding using member.guild.channels.cache..find()

Answer (score 0):

```
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'welcome');
```